# When javascript is blocked on Opera browser, to allow comments in Youtube to be showed, what urls should be included in the exceptions?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, javascript, youtube, opera

When blocking javascript globally and allowing "[*.]google.com" and "[*]youtube.com" on the exceptions list, Youtube will load ok and videos play as well, but the comments on the video pages won't load up.

On Chromium based browsers, what URL's (domains) should be included in the exceptions list in order to allow comments in Youtube to be shown?

Comment: You would have to study the resources that the page uses and find all relevant domains that it uses.  With a quick glance, I see oauth.googleusercontent.com, pagead2.goodlesyndication.com, ssl.gstatic.com, tpc.googlesyndication.com, www.googletagservices.com, etc...

Comment: Bible quote removed. Please don't include signatures/taglines/bible quotes in your questions. See [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5038)